# Should the 2sxc app need to be fully translated into the target language?

Tags: 2sxc

I've created basic 2sxc app and now trying to translate it into russian.

I've started with translating labels for entity properties and translated all of them (and only them), leaving all other stuff like placeholders in the default "auto" state.

But then I try to open entity edit form, it displays the following message: *"We have switched language to default en-us because it's missing some or all values"*. And displays all labels in english - as it says.

Is this an expected behavior? Maybe I miss some setting which affect it?

---

2sxc version is 11.4.0.

DNN version is 9.8.0.

Language pack for russian language for DNN is installed and working (though not 100% complete).

DNN UI language switching for other components are working as expected.

Both en-us and ru-ru languages are enabled in *App Management/Languages*.

2sxc extension itself is not translated into russian, AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

You probably started with a website where the initial content was added without a language specified. Because of this, the data has no language assigned - so when the form opens it has (default) content but doesn't have it saved in a way with a language assigned.

It *should* then just auto-assign the first language, but that has a bug which we haven't found time to fix yet. So for now, make sure you save the item once and then you should be able to edit additional languages for that item.

Comment: I also created an issue for this on github https://github.com/2sic/2sxc/issues/2356

Comment: Thanks, I will explore that.

Comment: I've recently re-imported my app (for testing purposes) to the same website but different folder. And now the issue is still showing up in the original app, but the copy is working as expected.

Comment: @Roman - this is because on import it matches the imported-data to the languages on your target system, so it kind of 'cleans' inconsistencies. The next release of 2sxc should also do this in the UI, we're working on it... 